# Returning array values, not the array iterator in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

How can I return the values of an array? The methods .values() and .entries() seem to return an Array Iterator. This is not what I want. I am also not allowed to modify func1() function for this edge case.

```
const test = func1();

console.log(test); // actual: [[1,2]] what I want: [1,2]

function func1() { // not allowed to modify func1
  return [func2()];
}

function func2() {
  const set = new Set();
  set.add(1);
  set.add(2);
  return Array.from(set); 
  // return Array.from(set).values() returns Array Iterator
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: What's the problem with using const test = func1()[0]?

Comment: You could flatten the result with `func1().flat();`.

Comment: in my use case the return value from func2 is not always an array. therefore, I want to see if its possible to just return the values.

Comment: But `func1` *always* returns an array, so it doesn't matter what `func2` returns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Bergi stated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67345799/2224657), `func1()` will always return an array, no matter what `func2()` returns. But there are a couple of ways to achieve this based on the return value of `func1()`.

You can either simply use the first element in the array `test[0]`, you can use the [`Array.flat()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat), or the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax). See the snippet below.

```js
const test = func1();

function func1() { // not allowed to modify func1
  return [func2()];
}

function func2() {
  const set = new Set();
  set.add(1);
  set.add(2);
  return Array.from(set); 
  // return Array.from(set).values() returns Array Iterator
}

// First element in array
console.log(test[0]);

// Array.flat()
console.log(test.flat());

// Spread operator
console.log(...test);
```

Comment: When the OP writes "*I am also not allowed to modify func1() function*", I doubt they want to modify the `console.log` call either.

Comment: This reply made me realize all options. Thanks.

Comment: @Bergi, you are right, it might not be ideal, but as you correctly stated, there is no other way if OP can't modify `func1()`, as it will always return an array. I will update my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible. `func1()` always returns an array with one element, it can never return `[1,2]`, not matter what `func2` does. You must modify its code.